# Strange Python thread behavior

Tags: python, multithreading

**EDIT**: Actually what happened was that I ran it in Programmer's Notepad and it waited for the program to complete before capturing the stdout output and printing it to console, then I ran it from mingw which worked as expected. This behavior is obvious and expected, I just haven't realized that I was running the program in programmer's notepad rather than shell as I usually do. My bad.

---

I was playing with Python threads, but ran into this weird problem where if I have a print statement and a 1 second sleep statement inside the callback function, it doesn't do the printing until the sum of the sleep times has elapsed.

here is the code that causes this behavior:

```
import threading
import time

def callback():
    for i in range(3):
        print "Hello, World!";
        time.sleep(1)

myThread = threading.Thread (
    target = callback, 
    args = []
)

myThread.start()
```

This is how I want it to behave:

```
public class Demo
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        (new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                System.out.println("Hello, World!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    // rethrow as an unchecked exception but do not silence it.
                    throw (RuntimeException)e; 
                }
            }
        })).start();
    }
}
```

What is causing Python to behave this way, and how can I get it to behave the way I expect it to?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. These both run exactly the same for me. They each print Hello, World! then wait a second, three times. How are they behaving for you?

Comment: for me the program halts for 3 seconds, then prints Hello world 3 times O.o

Comment: Wait, now it is working correctly and I didn't change the code... I'm confused.

Comment: It's suddenly working as expected :| I'm not sure if there is undefined behavior or if I changed something and didn't notice what, awkward.

Comment: I think I have a fix for you. See my answer.

Comment: Actually what happened was that I ran it in Programmer's Notepad and it waited for the program to complete before capturing the stdout output and printing it to console, then I ran it from mingw which worked as expected. This behavior is obvious and expected, I just haven't realized that I was running the program in programmer's notepad rather than shell as I usually do. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, I have a feeling that your problem is due to the system not flushing stdout. To fix it, try this:

```
import sys
```

Then right after your print function:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```